# How can I download from an ftp server in Matlab when behind a proxy?

Tags: matlab, ftp

MATLAB includes an `ftp` class such that in normal circumstances, I could do something like,

```
f = ftp(host,username,password);
mget(f, filename, targetfolder);
close(f);
```

However, my internet access is only through a proxy server, and the first line (which opens the connection) gives

```
Could not open a connection to "[hostname redacted]", port "21".
```

The documentation for `ftp` specifically says "The ftp function does not support proxy server settings.".

So, is there any other way in MATLAB to download something using ftp? The more modern stuff, which does support proxies, seems to be built around `websave`, but that seems to be entirely http-based.

Comment: As my knowledge of this subject is very limited, I can only give you a partial answer/suggestion. What you are trying to do sounds more like a job for bash (if you are on a unix system). If you insist, that it have to be through MATLAB, then you can use the function `system` or `unix` to execute bash commands from inside MATLAB. As for the specific bash command, I am not certain, though, if it was not for the proxy, you would use a something like `wget ftp:*adress*`

Comment: @NickyMattsson Thanks. Yeah, it could definitely be done from a linux command line. The hope was to fully automate in what otherwise needs to be a MATLAB script running in Windows, and I imagine that might be possible somehow via Powershell or something, but it'll probably not be worth it - I think just downloading the requisite stuff in a GUI ftp client first may be the eventual route.

Comment: Well, you could do it in MATLAB through the `system` function. Use the `computer` function to figure out whether the program runs on a system with Unix or MS-DOS, and then port the appropriate ftp command to the system using `system(*command*)`. Though, it will be a bit tedious compared to just downloading everything, you will have everything collected in your MATLAB function.